# Can Bubble.io be used for building native mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, bubble.io

I've watched some videos about Bubble.io that you can create mobile applications without code, in addition to building and linking the database of the system and doing the work/process flow of the App. Can this platform provide us with the functionality and build both the frontend and backend to release a native mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create web apps with Bubble.io and wrap them into native Android / iOS apps with the converter [Natively](https://www.buildnatively.com/). It allows enabling a lot of native features like push notifications, biometrics authorization, geolocation, universal links etc.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, FlutterFlow is a pretty great alternative to Bubble.io in building mobile apps in terms of functionalities. Bubble.io is preferable for apps that need quick pivoting (changes are made real-time to end users without having to rebuild the app and to require users to update their apps) yet it is incomparable to FlutterFlow and other mobile app builders in terms of UX. Fair trade off I think.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble.io is a perfect solution for MVP. The art of scale in an application developed in Bubble.io requires expertise. I would recommend creating a web app in bubble.io and creating APIs that can be integrated into a native application.

However, if you want to adapt the bubble.io application into a mobile app, this article might be helpful: https://bubble.io/blog/bubble-mobile-apps/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).